# Locating element by index is not working for elements having similar attributes

Tags: java, selenium, textbox, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am automating a web app in which I need to enter around 20 textboxes having similar attributes and below is the whole page HTML code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt  IE 9]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
<html lang="en"> 
<![endif]-->
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="max-age=36000000, public">
 <title>Table Administration Row Add Page</title>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/new.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo_table_jui.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/time.css">
 

 <style type="text/css">
 ul#css3menu1,ul#css3menu1 ul{
  margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;}
 ul#css3menu1,ul#css3menu1 .submenu{
  background-color:#FFFFFF;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#b2b2b4;-moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;}
 ul#css3menu1 .submenu{
  visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:-1px;top:100%;opacity:0;-moz-transition:all 0.5s;-webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s;-o-transition:opacity 0.5s,visibility 0.5s;transition:opacity 0.5s;float:left;z-index:2;background-color:#FFFFFF;background-image:-o-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(44,160,202,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.1)); background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(44,160,202,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.1));   background-image:linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(44,160,202,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.1));  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(44,160,202,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.1));border-width:1px;border-radius:0px 0px 4px 4px;-moz-border-radius:0px 0px 4px 4px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px;border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFFFF #bfc1c2 #bfc1c2 #bfc1c2;-moz-box-shadow:0 5px 5px rgba(20, 20, 25, 0.2), 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 5px rgba(20, 20, 25, 0.2), 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;box-shadow:0 5px 5px rgba(20, 20, 25, 0.2), 0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;padding:5px;}
 ul#css3menu1 li:hover>.submenu{
  visibility:visible;opacity:1;}
 ul#css3menu1 li{
  position:relative;display:block;white-space:nowrap;font-size:0;float:left;}
 ul#css3menu1 li:hover{
  z-index:1;}
 ul#css3menu1 ul .submenu{
  position:absolute;left:99%;top:0;border-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-color:#bfc1c2;}
 ul#css3menu1{
  font-size:0;z-index:999;position:relative;display:inline-block;zoom:1;padding:0;-moz-box-shadow:0 2px 0 #bfc1c2;-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 0 #bfc1c2;box-shadow:0 2px 0 #bfc1c2;
  *display:inline;}
 ul#css3menu1 .column{
  float:left;}
 * html ul#css3menu1 li a{
  display:inline-block;}
 ul#css3menu1>li{
  margin:0;}
 ul#css3menu1 a:active, ul#css3menu1 a:focus{
  outline-style:none;}
 ul#css3menu1 a{
  display:block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;font:14px 'Droid Sans', "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;color:#92979E;cursor:pointer;padding:13px 15px;background-color:;background-image:-o-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(85,85,85,0.13)); background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(85,85,85,0.13));   background-image:linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(85,85,85,0.13));  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(85,85,85,0.13));background-repeat:repeat;background-position:0 0;border-width:0px;border-style:none;border-color:;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0,startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#21555555)}
 ul#css3menu1 ul li{
  float:none;margin:0;}
 ul#css3menu1 ul a{
  text-align:left;padding:5px;-moz-box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;background-color:none;background-image:none;border-width:0;border-style:none;border-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;color:#92979E;text-decoration:none;}
 ul#css3menu1 li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li a.pressed{
  border-style:none;color:#92979E;background-image:-o-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(85,85,85,0.13),rgba(255,255,255,0)); background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(85,85,85,0.13),rgba(255,255,255,0));   background-image:linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(85,85,85,0.13),rgba(255,255,255,0));  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(85,85,85,0.13),rgba(255,255,255,0));background-position:0 100%;text-decoration:none;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0,startColorstr=#21555555,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)}
 ul#css3menu1 img{
  border:none;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:13px;}
 ul#css3menu1 ul span{
  background-image:none;padding-right:5px;}
 ul#css3menu1 ul li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 ul li a.pressed{
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0 #CF7E4C;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 #CF7E4C;box-shadow:0 1px 0 #CF7E4C;background-color:#ef9d58;background-image:-o-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(85,85,85,0.13)); background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(85,85,85,0.13));   background-image:linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(85,85,85,0.13));  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(85,85,85,0.13));border-style:none;color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0,startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#21555555)}
 ul#css3menu1 li.topfirst>a{
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-width:0 1px 0 0;border-style:solid;border-color:#bfc1c2;border-radius:5px 0 0 0;-moz-border-radius:5px 0 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;}
 ul#css3menu1 li.topfirst:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li.topfirst a.pressed{
  -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,20,50, 0.26) inset;-webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,20,50, 0.26) inset;box-shadow:0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,20,50, 0.26) inset;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-color:#bfc1c2;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;}
 ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu>a{
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-width:0 1px 0 0;border-style:solid;border-color:#bfc1c2;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;}
 ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li.topmenu a.pressed{
  -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,20,50, 0.26) inset;-webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,20,50, 0.26) inset;box-shadow:0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,20,50, 0.26) inset;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-color:#bfc1c2;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;}
 ul#css3menu1 li.toplast>a{
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #FFFFFF inset;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-width:0px;border-style:solid;border-color:#bfc1c2;border-radius:0 5px 0 0;-moz-border-radius:0 5px 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:0;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;}
 ul#css3menu1 li.toplast:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li.toplast a.pressed{
  -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,20,50, 0.26) inset;-webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,20,50, 0.26) inset;box-shadow:0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0,20,50, 0.26) inset;background-color:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-color:#bfc1c2;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;}
 </style>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.92.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jqueryshim.js'></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddslick.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="js/jqueryui-min.js"></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquerytimeaddon.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function checkSubmitSearch(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
   quickSearch();
  else
   return false;
 }
 function quickSearch() {
  if (document.getElementById("txtQuickSearch").value == ""
    || isNaN(document.getElementById("txtQuickSearch").value)) {
   alert("Please enter a valid Template ID");
  } else {
   window.location = "templateModify.action?templateID="
   + document.getElementById("txtQuickSearch").value + "&Search=y";
  }

 }
</script>
</head>
 <body>
   

<script type="text/javascript">
 function selectLanguage(value) {
  document.location.href = "locale.action?request_locale=" + value;
  document.forms[0].submit();
 }
 
 function searchHelp() {
 
  window.open('/AdminPortal/jsp/SearchHelp.jsp#RTAdmin', "_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=840, height=630");
     }
     
function templateHelp() {
 
  window.open('/AdminPortal/jsp/TemplateAdministartionHelp.jsp#RTAgent', "_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=840, height=630");
     }
     
function help() {
  window.open('/AdminPortal/jsp/Help.jsp', '',
       'height=630,width=840,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resize:no,overflow:auto');
     } 
</script>
<div class="containermain">
 <span style="float: right">Logged in as :<a
  href="userDetails.action?userno=636">Testaccount2@trx.com</a><br>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <a href=""onclick="return templateHelp()">Help</a>        
  </span>
 <!--     
  -->
 <!--<a href="/AdminPortal/locale.action?request_locale=en">English</a>
 <a href="/AdminPortal/locale.action?request_locale=es">Spanish</a>
 <a href="/AdminPortal/locale.action?request_locale=fr">France</a>
 <a href="/AdminPortal/locale.action?request_locale=de">Germany</a>-->

 <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <!--<select name="language" id="language" onchange="selectLanguage(this.value)"><option value="-1" onchange="selectLanguage(this.value)">Select Language</option><option value="en" onchange="selectLanguage(this.value)">English</option><option value="es" onchange="selectLanguage(this.value)">Spanish</option><option value="fr" onchange="selectLanguage(this.value)">France</option><option value="de" onchange="selectLanguage(this.value)">Germany</option><option value="fi" onchange="selectLanguage(this.value)">Finnish</option></select>-->
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
   <div id="menu">
    <ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
     <li class="topfirst"><a href="welcome.action" title="Home"
      style="height: 24px; line-height: 24px;">Home</a></li>
     <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" title="Configurations"
      style="height: 24px; line-height: 24px;"><span>Configuration</span></a>
      <div class="submenu" style="width: 230px;">
       <div class="column" style="width: 100%">
        <ul>
         
         <li><a href="appConfig">Configure Applications </a></li>
         
         <li><a href="hierarchyMatadataDetails">Configure Hierarchy MetaData </a></li>
         
         <li><a href="hierarchyData">Configure Hierarchy Data </a></li>
         
         <li><a href="userList">User Management </a></li>

         <li><a href="roleList">Role Definition </a></li>

        </ul>
       </div>
      </div></li>

     
     <li class="topmenu"><a href="templateMapping"
      title="Mapping Template" style="height: 24px; line-height: 24px;"><span>Mapping Template</span></a></li>
     
     <li class="topmenu"><a href="settings"
      title="Settings" style="height: 24px; line-height: 24px;"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
     
     <li class="topmenu"><a href="mailSearchApplication"
      title="Search" style="height: 24px; line-height: 24px;"><span>Search</span></a></li>
     
     <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" title="Operations"
      style="height: 24px; line-height: 24px;"><span>Operations</span></a>
      <div class="submenu" style="width: 230px;">
       <div class="column" style="width: 100%">
        <ul>
         

         <li><a href="preprocessorApplication">PreProcessor </a></li>
         

         <li><a href="systemProperties">System Information </a></li>
         

         <li><a href="volumeStatsPage">Volume Stats </a></li>
         

         <li><a href="searchLogsPage">System Logs </a></li>
         

         <li><a href="tableAdministration.action">Table Operations </a></li>
         

         <li><a href="templateCustom">Template Administration </a></li>
         

         <li><a href="requestHandling.action">Request Handling </a></li>
         
       <!--commenting the Resend Email Requests part and  Generate Email Requests as of now, it might get used in feature -->
       <!--<li><a href="resendEmailsRequestsPage" title="Resend Email Request">Resend Email Requests</a></li>       
       <li><a href="generateEmailsRequestsPage" title="Generate Email Requests">Generate Email Requests</a></li>-->
     <!--commenting the Application Transformations part -->
     <<li><a href="applicationTransformationsPage" title="ApplicationTransformations">Application Transformations</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div></li>
     

     
     <li class="toplast"><a
      href="/AdminPortal/j_spring_security_logout"
      style="height: 24px; line-height: 24px;">SignOut</a></li>
    </ul>

   </div>
   
   <div class="quicksearch">
    <span style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;"> <input
     type="text" value="" id="txtQuickSearch" name="txtQuickSearch"
     onkeypress="checkSubmitSearch(event)" placeholder='Quick Search' />
    </span>
   </div>

   
  <!--  <div><input value="Help" onclick="return help()"/>
 </div>
 <a href="/AdminPortal/jsp/Help.jsp">Help</a>-->

   <div style="clear: both"></div>

<script>
 function cancelAdd() {
  document.forms[0].action = "tableAdministrationSearch.action";
  document.forms[0].submit();
 }
</script>

<div >
 <h3>
  Table Operations
 </h3>
 <p>
  User can Insert Values
 </p>
 <p>
  Please leave the textbox blank if null needs to be inserted
 </p>
 

 
 <form name="tableAdministrationAddSave" id="tableAdministrationAddSave" action="/AdminPortal/tableAdministrationAddSave.action" method="post">
 <table width="100%" align="center">
 <tr>
 <td>

  <label class="labelboldClass" for="name">Table Name
   TRANS_RAIL_STATIONS </label>
  
   <table width="100%">
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">RAILSTATION_CODE:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">RAILSTATION_NAME_UC:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">RAILSTATION_NAME:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">COUNTRY:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">STATE:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">MAIN_CITY_NAME:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">en_US:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">en_UK:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">es_ES:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">fr_FR:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">de_DE:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">nl_NL:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">it_IT:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">fi_FI:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">df_DF:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">ru_RU:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">zh_CN:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>**
    
     <tr>
      <td align="left" width="20%">fr_CA:</td>
      <td width="80%"><input type="text" name="rowValue" style="position:relative"></td>
     </tr>
    
   
   </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

   <div class="submitWrapper" align="center">
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" id="tableAdministrationAddSave_0"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="tableAdministrationAddSave_2" onclick="cancelAdd()"></input>
   </div>
  
 </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

I have tried using below WebDriver code to enter values for above textboxes but its entering only first text box and getting error no such element exception for reaming.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='rowValue'][1]")).sendKeys("Test1");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='rowValue'][2]")).sendKeys("Test2");
```

It would be very helpful if anyone could help me to enter all textboxes. Let me know if anyone need more details on same.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you share the URL of the page under which these text boxes exist?

Comment: You can do this by using a for loop and setting your xpath

Comment: @Anirudh - Sorry, am not allowed to give access webpage to outside users.

Comment: @Naveen - It would be helpful if you share code snippet how I can do by using for loop. I tried using for loop,it but it dint worked.

Comment: @chivas_hvn please provide your whole Page so that i can suggest you the xpath

Comment: Can you check if after entering the a value in the first text box, the attribute 'name' for the others doesn't change dynamically?

Comment: @Anirudh - I have checked and attribute name is not changing dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix - you can use list of webelements:

```
List<WebElement> listname = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='rowValue']");
listname.get(1).sendKeys("Test1");
listname.get(2).sendKeys("Test2");
```

etc.

Comment: I have tried your code but it appears we can not use indexing for List WebElement in `[0],[1]..` format.  So I tried with `listname .add(index, element);` format but it also did not worked.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, of course it should be listname.get(1).sendKeys("Test1")

Comment: Now am able to enter values to all text boxes. Many Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If those are not generated at runtime, you can give id's to all html elements(textboxes here) and use

```
.findElements(By.id)
```

method instead of

```
.findElements(By.xpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add parenthesis to your `xpath`, which should looks like this: `(//input[@name='rowValue'])[?]`

Comment: Parenthesis to xpath did not worked when I have written in `(//input[@name='rowValue'])[1]` format.